# Как можно реализовать запрос из консоли с помощью scanner, чтобы допустим вводить /cost product1234, а выводило его цену?

Tags: java, sql, scanner

```
public class Main {
    private static Connection connection;
    private static Statement statement;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        connect();
        try {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.execute("DELETE FROM Goods");
            statement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Goods (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, prodid INTEGER, title TEXT, cost INTEGER)");
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
                statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Goods (prodid, title, cost) VALUES ('prod_id" + i + "', 'product" + i + "', '0" + i + "');");
            }
            connection.setAutoCommit(true);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        disconnect();
    }

    public static void connect() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:MainDB.db");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void disconnect() {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В вопросе уже содержится ответ. Реализовать с помощью Scanner.

Comment: Я понимаю, но не могу сообразить как именно должна выглядеть эта конструкция.

Comment: Пример для Scanner: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class-in-java